# Using function names as variables in python

Tags: python

I had an interesting (potentially stupid) idea: What happens if I use a built-in function name as a variable to assign some object (say integer). Here's what I tried:

```
 >>> a = [1,2,3,4]
 >>> len(a)
 4
 >>> len = 1
 >>> len(a)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
 TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Seems like python does not treat function and variable names differently. Without restarting the python interpreter, is there a way to assign `len` back to the function? Or undo the assignment `len = 1`?

Comment: Python treats functions and methosd as first class objects, which is why you can assign to them and pass them to other functions around.

Comment: It is true that Python does not treat function and variable names differently. This is key to being able to use functions as first-class objects without having to do anything like Ruby's `:func`, Lisp's `'func`, etc.

Comment: You dind't actually overwrite it, you masked it. Just deleting the new `len` variable will then unmask the builtin name. No need to import from `__builtin__`.

Comment: BTW, I have my vim editor color builtin names differently, so I am always reminded by my editor if I use a builtin name.

Comment: many IDE's will warn you if you do this (read Eclipse + pydev, pycharm, and probably others)

Comment: That is what I suspected, ty. I've been playing around in the interpreter till now. Going to try out pycharm for my first python project as I use intelliJ for java.

Comment: pycharm is worth every penny

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically you can get it back from `__builtin__`

```
from __builtin__ import len
```

But please don't name stuff `len`, it makes sensible programmers angry.

Okay, for a start don't name your variable after the builtins, secondly if you want to respect other functions then respect namespaces for example

```
import time
time.asctime()
asctime = 4253
time.asctime() # Notice that asctime here is unaffected as its inside the time module(s) namespace
```

Comment: I agree that I shouldn't use `len` as a variable name. But how do I ensure that I do not overwrite a function name defined in another module?

Comment: Makes sense. Is it considered bad practice to import only the function you need? `from time import asctime` This way you can call `asctime()` without namespacing it, which brings us back to square one.

Comment: @fo_x86 it's not bad practice, but the explicit > implicit mantra from the zen of python leads to module.function usage. Python gives you the possibility to shoot yourself in the foot, allowing for shadowing builtins, because 'We're all consenting adults here'. You can decide for yourself.

Comment: That's my advice too; if you have a lot of namespace conflicts, don't import things quite as specifically.

Answer (score 18):

Use `del len`:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> len=15
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del len
>>> len(a)
4
```

From [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#del):

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError exception will be raised